# Inter Process Communication FIFO java

Tags: java, ipc, fifo, mkfifo

Hi I'm trying to Implement a IPC in Java with FIFO
I cretaed a FIFO with with

```
mkfifo temp
```

then I tried to open and FileWriter with

```
BufferedWriter writeStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writePipePath));
```

but it blocks at this line.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What does your reading code look like?  If you have no reader, it should block.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats it!
I have 2 pipes for each application(one for sending, one for receiving). But both of the application wanted to open the send Pipe first.

Comment: You could use a Socket and a ServerSocket as this has two streams (one in, one out) will be cleaned up when the program exists, though you will have the same issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [`mkfifo` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo), opening a fifo will block until both sides are open. `FileWriter` opens the named pipe synchronously - i.e., it will not return until the pipe is also opened for reading, by another process or another thread.